# Gem Harness - MAZDA 2 1.6 2011

Tags: wiring, mazda-3

Can someone please explain to me what is `Gem Harness`? Is it something to do with wiring? Searched the net but could not find any convincing answer anywhere.

The primary reason I am asking is because `mazda` service center has given me a quote of `2000USD` for the parts only and around `500USD` for service.

Regards,
Y

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much clarity either, on the "Required Maintenance Sheet" it is mentioned "Gem Harness" and the corresponding price, when I called the service center they told me it is to do with the wires, but when I look at the cost it is way too high, hence I am asking it here

Comment: I think you should ask another question about the problem you were experiencing that motivated you to take the car to the Mazda service center.  Perhaps someone can assist you with the core issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GEM stands for Generic Electronics Module. Its a control module for the cabin electronics (windows, locks, etc). The GEM harness is the wiring that leads up to or from the module. It is a harness made of multiple parts and replacing it completely is a bit of a crazy thing. You usually tend to troubleshoot and find the bad part and repair it.

$2000USD + $500 for labor is crazy. I don't know which Mazda you have but the GEM usually goes for around $300-$500.

Take the car to a mechanic who can diagnose the issue rather than try to change the whole thing and leave you bankrupt.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. Another question in my mind, does GEM also connects to OBD2 port on the dash?

Comment: I'm sorry but dont have the schematic required to know. Some cars do, some dont. :)